# How to write an extended gtk.CellRendererText() to have an image beside the text

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtkbuilder

I am doing a simple file browser in python and GtkBuilder. I am using a Treeview that has one TreeViewColumn with cells that are rendered like:

```
self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
```

As I mentioned I am creating a file browser. So I want to have a small icon before the text in each cell, that icon will be the folder,file icon. Any idea on how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to extend CellRendererText, you can insert more than one CellRenderer per column using [gtk.TreeViewColumn.pack_start()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html#method-gtktreeviewcolumn--pack-start).

You will want to have a CellRendererPixbuf to the left of your CellRendererText.

Comment: But can you show how to do it? because pack_start() takes only 2 arguments (CellRenderer,Boolean)

Comment: Ok I did it by calling pack_start() two times.